# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paddle.fluid.core_noavx'?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pip, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I install paddle_ocr and paddlepaddle packages also but i got an Error (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paddle.fluid.core_noavx'). how to solve this type of error provide your suggestions here...below my code was attached

```
 from paddleocr import PaddleOCR,draw_ocr
# Paddleocr supports Chinese, English, French, German, Korean and Japanese.
# You can set the parameter `lang` as `ch`, `en`, `french`, `german`, `korean`, `japan`
# to switch the language model in order.
ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en') # need to run only once to download and load model into memory
img_path = 'PaddleOCR/doc/imgs_en/img_12.jpg'
result = ocr.ocr(img_path, cls=True)
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors, current output, expected output), as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Only plot images are okay. _A proper question **MUST** provide **ALL** of the information necessary in order for a proper answer to be given._

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `paddle` package is developed for multiple platforms including non-x86 architectures that don't have the AVX instruction set.  When the package is compiled for each architecture it checks if AVX is implemented and then modifies the packaging to have either the `paddle.fluid.core_avx` or `paddle.fluid.core_noavx` namespace.

If you want to handle this programmatically, `paddle.fluid.core` has a variable `has_noavx_core` that you can check.

```py
from paddle.fluid.core import has_noavx_core

if has_noavx_core:
    import paddle.fluid.core_noavx as core_noavx
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but the same error display

Comment: Now, I also attached my code here please check it

Answer (score 0):

The machine does not support avx, you can try:

```
python3 -m pip install paddlepaddle-gpu==2.0.2 -f https://paddlepaddle.org.cn/whl/stable/noavx.html
```

If the CPU environment is used, remove the gpu